# How to find letters/font .bmp

Tags: fonts, ascii

I need to find a .bmp file for each letter or for the whole ascii table in the same font, each file has to have the same dimensions.
Does anyone knows where I can find that kind of pictures ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you not create the images yourself? Even manually it wouldn't take long, but you could automate/script it easily enough.

Comment: I'm not sure, I dont know anything about graphic... I need it to code an interface, but I cant use .ttf or font files, only bmp or array of integers

Comment: That seems strange... Are you sure you don't need a bitmap font? Which is usually 1 image

Comment: If not would you mind sharing the details of the framework or whatever it is that is limiting you to individual bmp files?

Comment: Any restrictions on what particular font you need? "The same dimensions" suggest your image for the letter `i` should be as wide as for `M`, which – whatever your application is – would look hideous with a proportional font. Unless, of course, you need the *images* in the same size but don't mind lots of metadata that describes left and right sidebearings and the 'actual' width of each character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a strange workaround but you could input you font to [this program](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/) and export it as a bitmap, then adapt your work.
I used it myself for a website that could only display bitmaps inside buttons.